# How often do enderman pick up/place blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How often will Enderman pick up/place blocks that they are eligible to? Their NBT doesn't seem to have a timer and increasing the random tick rate rule doesn't seem to speed up the process. Picking up blocks are clearly much faster than placing them down.

Answer (score 1):

Although there *is* a random chance they will pick up their eligible blocks (unless they are summoned with commands specifically preventing them to) they can **only pick up blocks that are in a 4x4x3 area regardless if they choose to**.

Comment: Even if there isn't a set timer, there must be some logic that makes them pickup blocks, and that logic could be possibly converted to a frequency. If it is a random chance, depending on how often that function is called, you could estimate how often they pickup blocks. Also, why is the area relevant, since we are talking about frequency?

Comment: I did some research, and yes, there actually is a random chance that they will pick up blocks (so you were right about that; I was just telling you based on my experience), but they will still check for a 4x4x3 area, or they still won't pick it up even if they want to.

For more information, read the 4th paragraph under the "Behavior" section.

[Endermen - Wiki Fandom](https://minecraft-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Enderman)